# How can `fsetpos()` be used to "allow random access on files that are too large to handle with `fseek()`?"

Tags: c, c99, stdio

While I understand that `fpos_t` is an opaque type intended to be initialized by the `fgetpos()` function , §7.19.9.1 of the [C99 rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) states that:

> `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` were added to C89 to allow random access operations on files that are too large to handle with `fseek` and `ftell`.

and §7.19.9.2:

> The need to encode both record position and position within a record in a `long` value may constrain the size of text files upon which `fseek` and `ftell` can be used to be considerably smaller than the size of binary files.
>
> ...
>
> `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` were added to deal with files that are too large to handle with `fseek` and `ftell`.

This seems to primarily focus on text files (files opened with a `mode` excluding the `b` flag), because some implementations may require storing two positions (a file record position and a record character position), which could significantly reduce the effective range of the `fseek()` and `ftell()` functions for text streams.

Nevertheless, I'm clueless as to how this is particularly useful for text streams, and I certainly don't understand how it could effectively be used for "random access."

It seems the only way to actually utilize these functions is by reading every character of a file and caching their `fgetpos()`d `fpos_t` values, which seems niche at best, since you almost certainly don't want to read anywhere near `LONG_MAX` characters.

What was "the Committee" thinking? Is there a C99 rationale rationale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that on some (probably <s>archaic</s> mainframe) systems text files are stored as series of "records" (lines) and the file position therefore is made up both a record index and a position within the record, which is what the rationale text seems to be referring to. At the operating system level, the seek operation requires both a record index and position within the record, rather than a byte position within the file; this leads to the problem that both record index and position within must be encoded within a `long` value for use with `fseek` and `ftell`. Therefore, a library implementation needs to assign some number of bits to each of record index and position, and this limits the number of records and the position.

For example, if `long` has 32 bits, then this might be divided into 25 bits for the record index and 7 bits for the position within the record (allowing a maximum usable record length of 127, and 2^25 ~= 33k records). The system may however allow more and larger records than this.

(Above statements are partly vague recollection, and partly inference from the rationale text).

However, the real problem with `fseek` and `ftell` on even modern desktop systems is that a `long` value may not be enough to represent the full range of file positions. On 32-bit systems `long` is usually 32 bits, but files can often still grow to be larger than 2GB. Therefore a different mechanism for specifying file offsets is required.

> I certainly don't understand how it could effectively be used for "random access."

In this case by "random access" what they are talking about is the ability to seek to any point that has already been visited, that is, you can reposition (using `fsetpos`) any position that you have already obtained (via `fgetpos`). It is not about seeking to any arbitrary byte position. Arguably "random access" is the wrong term, but I think they just wanted to distinguish from purely sequential access.

Comment: +1, but IBM mainframes aren't any more archaic than ASCII or POSIX:  http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/index.html